# Why HtmlHlper does not work when '@' sign is not given?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

in a view file I added following code block. (To make this clean, I have omitted code blocks which are not necessary.)

```
         <div>

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Step1.Locations.Count; i++)
            {

                Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Step1.Locations[i].City);
                Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Step1.Locations[i].Country);
                <br/>

            }
        </div>
```

This won't show text boxes for above code block, although iteration properly works, when I do the debugging.

Then I changed above code block as follow,

```
            <div>
            <table>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Step1.Locations.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Step1.Locations[i].City)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Step1.Locations[i].Country)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
```

And that works properly. 
Do we have to add '@' sign explicitly? 
Because in first code block these HtmlHelpers are used within the curly brackets of 'for' loop, so I thought '@' sign would not be required.

Can you please explain facts behind this?

Thank you.

Comment: You should first read how Razor works and how it interprets where HTML code is and where C# code is

Comment: go through this once http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/getting-started-with-razor-view-engine-in-mvc-3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `@` symbol, you're saying "If the result of this code returns something, output it."

If you don't put the `@` in the front, the code will execute but nothing will render.